# Open random video file on a keypress

Tags: python, keyboard

I am trying to write a program in Python that will open a random video file on a keypress(for me F8). I am very new to coding and currently stuck. I got it to the point where I am not getting any errors but now the program is not sticking around. Not sure what to do next. My code:

```
import os
import keyboard
import string
import random
from openfile import openfile


path = r"C:\Users\Rudy\Videos\GIFS"

letter = string.ascii_letters 
digit = string.digits     
def keyboardPress():
    mp3Select = random.choice(os.listdir(path)) 
    keypress = str(path + "\\" + mp3Select) 
    while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('F8'): 
                openfile(keypress)
            break

def main():
    while True:
        try:
            keyboardPress()
        except:
            pass

main()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `openfile` module. Please explain what you want to happen. Do you want the program to stop and play the video?

Comment: What do you mean program is not sticking around? Be precise.

Comment: My idea for the program is for it to be on the lookout for the F8 key to be pressed and then plays a video by opening a file in that file path. I also want the program to be continuing to run so it can keep playing videos everytime the key is pressed. 

By not sticking around I mean that program closes immediately after I run it.

Answer (score 0):

**To open a random video on key press**, you can use the event hooks in the `keyboard` module, one such event hook is [`keyboard.on_press(callback)`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardon_presscallback-suppressfalse) which invokes a callback for every keydown event.

**To prevent the program from terminating,** you can use the method [`keyboard.wait(hotkey=None)`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardwaithotkeynone-suppressfalse-trigger_on_releasefalse) which blocks the program execution until the given hotkey is pressed.

Use:

```
def keyPress(event):
    if event.name == 'f8': # filter the `f8` key press event
        fileName = random.choice(os.listdir(path))
        filePath = os.path.join(path, fileName)
        openfile(filePath) # open the video file

def main():
    keyboard.on_press(keyPress) # hook up the event handler
    keyboard.wait('esc') # blocks the program execution until `escape` key is pressed.

main()
```

---

Edit (see comments):

Use this while calling `main()`:

```
try:
    main()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: Went ahead and added this to my current code, substituting the 2 def sections I had. It still seems to be terminating the program immediately. Not sure if I did something wrong though.

Comment: I'm not sure about the working of `openfile` module seems like there might be a problem there. Any error messages?

Comment: Can you tell a little more about `openfile` function?

Comment: I sadly don't know much about it myself. I saw someone else using it and thought that it would work out well here. If there is anything else you would recommend I can try that.

Comment: If you are on windows, try using `os.startfile(filePath)` in place of `openfile`.

Comment: Still same problem with it immediately being terminated.

Comment: Does the program is running at all? or Is it just terminated without even pressing any keys?

Comment: Terminating without pressing any keys

Comment: Well, in that case you have to debug/identify the cause which is preventing the program from starting.

Comment: How would I do that? Not to sure what to look for while debugging?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what try/except blocks are but could that be used to fix this issue?

Comment: That's not going to help in this case. Just check if the python environment on you computer is set up properly and all the required modules are installed.

Comment: `try:
    main()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)` and let me know what's the output of this.

Comment: Seems to pop up and then immediately get terminated.

Comment: You should try writing a python program without any imports with a simple `print` statement and check whether it can run, if it does not then there is a problem with python installation on your computer.

Comment: This was my code and it worked fine: 
    print ("hello")
    input('Press ESC to exit')